# Is の omitted in these cases?

Tags: particle-の, nouns

I recently watched a film called

> パパはわるものチャンピオン

and wondered whether the particle 'の' had been omitted between 'わるもの' and 'チャンピオン' in the film's title. Similarly, my mind turned to phrases like

> 東京大学

Is there a reason for the lack of 'の' between these sets of nouns? 
Thank you! (Sorry to waste time with what is probably a very simple question...)

Comment: Pretty much! Thank you for the link. I definitely now understand the 東京大学 example but, my first example is still a bit unclear to me... It doesn't fit with any of the 3 cases in the top answer.

Comment: @UndoubtedlyDean I think that it's case #3.